# SSIS Conditional Split NULL handling

Tags: sql-server, ssis, conditional-split

I am trying to update records from an SSIS conditional split to destinations after comparing them but I am stuck on NULL values.
I have a source table with 128 columns that needs to be compared to destination  to find records to update, unfortunately I cannot compare NULL values together or the result of the condition will be False as it cannot compare NULLs. Is there a way to easily compare Source and Destination records handling NULL values as string or any other way to avoid failure ? Thanks

Comment: how do you compare those now? you could try use `ISNULL(column,'NULL')` to compare with the string NULL not actual `NULL`

Comment: Sure but how to handle it with a huge number of columns ? I will need to add 2 checks on each ?

Comment: yes, you need to do that

Comment: I would read this question but now that I've seen the ridiculous comment I can't bring myself to read what the question is about, don't dump stuff like this in the comments: `(SRC_ACT_PLN == DST_ACT_PLN) && (SRC_AG_ADD == DST_AG_ADD) && (SRC_AG_CITY == DST_AG_CITY).......` Add it to the question with an explanation.

Comment: Sorry, need to start somewhere ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `ISNULL(column,'NULL')` to compare with the string NULL not actual `NULL`.

If both source and destination have `NULL`, you need to add `ISNULL` on both side, for example, `ISNULL(Source_col,'NULL') = ISNULL(Target_col,'NULL')`

Also, if you do not need to compare those `NULL`, you could filter out those `NULL` first, and it will grant your a better performance during the runtime.

For example, you could conditional split the source `where col is not null` and set the destination `select * From table where col1 is not null and col2 is not null`, etc.

**UPDATE**

In your case, it will be:

`(ISNULL(SRC_ACT_PLN,'NULL') == ISNULL(DST_ACT_PLN,'NULL'))` (same for the others) , but keep in mind that if both source and destination are `NULL`, it will still be returned as `TRUE`, otherwise, do what I suggest above, handle(filter out) `NULL` first then do the comparison.

Comment: So as I understand, it will be something like : (ISNULL(SRC_ACT_PLN,'NULL') = ISNULL(DST_ACT_PLN,'NULL') || ISNULL(SRC_ACT_PLN,'NULL') = ISNULL(DST_ACT_PLN,'NULL')) &&
 (SRC_ACT_PLN == DST_ACT_PLN)

Comment: @OwenS, exactly, check my updated answer for some attentions.

Comment: I cannot filter out NULL values as I have most of it in different fields , sometimes on the source, sometimes on the destination, sometimes both but as I have many columns, it is complicated to comprare the full set with good performance. Thanks

Comment: @OwenS, you could use `SQL query` as both `input` and `output`, and I do not think it is a good design having more than hundred columns in one table xD

Comment: @OwenS, if the field is in data type `INT`, etc, replace the `'NULL'` with `0`, etc. It will also give a better performance when comparing the numeric values when you have a large data set.

Comment: Unfortunaltely I am not responsible of the design and the NULL values could be present in any data type :/ If I do it like this : (ISNULL(SRC_ACT_PLN,'NULL') = ISNULL(DST_ACT_PLN,'NULL') || ISNULL(SRC_ACT_PLN,'NULL') = ISNULL(DST_ACT_PLN,'NULL')) && (SRC_ACT_PLN == DST_ACT_PLN) Which operator should I use to make sur it works in each condition ? NULL / NOT NULL / SRC=DST

Comment: Just `=` if you are doing the equal comparison.